# Running development version of create-react-app in Apache

Tags: reactjs, apache, apache2, development-environment

I've looked around for this everywhere and there is tonnes of documentation on how to DEPLOY apps created with create-react-app to apache which is fairly straight forward, however there's barely anything on how to run your development environment on apache.

I'm working on an app that's going to be deployed on an apache server and so I want to mimic the environment during development but can't figure out how to set it up correctly. Is it even possible?

I have the following conf file set up for my site - but because the index.html file doesn't directly include the JS required for React to do its magic, I just get an empty page with the `<div id="root"></div>` holder.

Conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName   warehouse.local.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/warehouse-local/public        
  ErrorLog     /var/log/apache2/warehouse.local.com-error_log 
  CustomLog    /var/log/apache2/warehouse.local.com-access_log common

  <Directory /var/www/warehouse.local.com>
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Anyone got any advice on how to achieve what I'm after?

Comment: Amazed there aren't answers to this question.  Even just a point to a link?

Comment: @DaveKanter yeah I struggled for a bit but I must have found some sort of solution because the app is live and working a treat now. I'll have a look back over and see if there's anything I can post here to help others. I can't remember what my solution actually ended up being off the top of my head.